# The operator is undefined

Tags: java, operator-keyword

I just tried to make a simple class that lets me figure out the length of a file:

```
public class Size {

    long s = 0;
    int a;

    public static void main(String[]args){
        new Size();
    }

    Size(){

        try{
        FileInputStream str = new FileInputStream("E:/Eclipse/Resources/smile.jpg");

        while(a != null){
            s++;
        }
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


}
```

I run into a problem with

```
while(a != null)
```

I get the Error:

> The operator != is undefined for the argument type(s) int, null

Any ideas why it's blocking the condition?

Comment: Because `int` can't be `null`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Primitive types in Java cannot be `null`. If you want to check for 0, do `a != 0`.

Comment: I was thinking about that but sometimes the stream has a 0 so it would terminate after just a few bytes.

Answer (score 7):

Put `a` into an `Integer` object, which *can* be compared to `null`:

```
Integer value = new Integer(a);

while (value != null)
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should assign (or) check `NULL` values only for a pointer. For integer values, initialise it to any number ,like a flag and check for that condition. `NULL can be assigned or checked only with a pointer variable`

Comment: Ok so I can't check for null but how else can I check if the stream has ended?

Comment: you have to set a flag instead. ie. if the stream has ended, put a=0 and then check if a==0

Comment: Ohhh ok I just found the flag it goes to -1 when the stream is over.